# How to log the output of a daemon application?

Tags: console, java, initrd, daemon

I have a Java program running as a daemon (thanks to YAJSW, a wrapper for java).

The thing is that this java application writes several lines of console text, (simply imagine a Hello World App). If I run it from the console of course I can read those lines.

But when it runs as a daemon, where do those lines of text go?

Comment: The lines of text go wherever YAJSW made them go.

Comment: @Gilles you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to do it in the Yajsw help,

thanks @Gilles for the guiding

It's enough just to specify in wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.logfile= <path and filename >
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you run the app using `svscan` ([homepage](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svscan.html), part of daemontools)?

If you configure correctly you'll have something like this:

```
app/log/main/current
```

And the current file is the console output.

I use `svscan` to run C++, Java, Groovy and linux common services.

Comment: I've solved it, but +1 thanks anyway